# How can I make Powershell run a file without a .exe extension?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm using mingw32-make to compile a small C++ file. The file is just a file that prints "Hello, World!".

```
CC=g++

images: 
    $(CC) main.cpp -o project2.out
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, whenever I try to run the project2.out executable through the Powershell terminal integrated in Visual Studio Code, it doesn't print anything to the console. I tried using the Windows Powershell application and it tries asking me what application I want to open. Adding .exe to the name of the file, it works completely fine. Is there any way to run this in powershell as an application without adding the .exe to the filename?

Comment: From what I know, on Windows, any file that can be executed should have either .exe or .bat extensions.

Comment: You're not generating an executable just yet, you still need to use the linker

Comment: Adding .exe to the file name makes it work perfectly file, what I'm wondering is how I can make the file run without adding the .exe extension. Doing `./project2.out` doesn't work, but adding the .exe extension then doing `./project2.out` does work.

Comment: Do not insist in the file extension `.out`. Just remove it. The compiler will append `.exe` for you. Then Powershell will happily run the command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under `CMD.EXE` the `PATHEXT` environment variable determines what is considered an executable file. Looks like the same variable is honored by PowerShell.

On my system, this variable is set to:

```
PS> $env:PATHEXT
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
```

If I create an executable, rename it from, say, `foo.exe` to `foo.out`. Then add `.out` to this variable, it works to launch it by just `foo`.

```
PS> # build executable foo.exe
PS> mv foo.exe foo.out
PS> $env:PATHEXT="$env:PATHEXT;.OUT"
PS> .\foo
```